# Change the binding of a Proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
 l = lambda { a }
 def some_function
     a = 1
 end
```

I just want to access `a` by the lambda and a special scope which has defined `a` already somewhere like inside `some_function` in the example, or just soon later in the same scope as:

```
 l = lambda { a }
 a = 1
 l.call
```

Then I found when calling `l`, it is still using its own binding but not the new one where it was called.

And then I tried to use it as:

```
 l.instance_eval do
     a = 1
     call
 end
```

But this also failed, it is strange that I can't explain why.

I know the one of the solution is using `eval`, in which I could special a binding and executing some code in text, but I really do not want to use as so.

And, I know it is able to use a global variable or instance variable. However, actually my code is in a deeper embedded environment, so I don't want to break the completed parts if not quite necessary.

I have referred the `Proc` class in the documentation, and I found a function names `binding` that referred to the `Proc`'s context. While the function only provided a way to access its binding but cannot change it, except using `Binding#eval`. It evaluate text also, which is exactly what I don't like to do.

Now the question is, do I have a better (or more elegant) way to implement this? Or using `eval` is already the *regular* manner?

Edit to reply to @Andrew:
Okay, this is a problem which I met when I'm writing a lexical parser, in which I defined a array with fixed-number of items, there including at least a `Proc` and a regular expression. My purpose is to matching the regular expressions and execute the Procs under my special scope, where the Proce will involved some local variables that should be defined later. And then I met the problem above.
Actually I suppose it is not same completely to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245947/is-it-possible-to-access-blocks-scope-in-method/9246066#9246066), as mine is how to pass *in* binding to a Proc rather than how to pass it *out*.

@Niklas:
Got your answer, I think that is what exactly I want. It has solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: Perhaps a good question to ask is *why* do you want to do this, or, rather, what are you trying to ultimately achieve?

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know. I'd be interested in an answer to this exact question, rather than a solution to the underlying problem :)

Comment: @NiklasB. I agree, but knowing the end-goal can help understand the problem better. And I'm pretty sure I answered a question similar to this a while back, and I'm trying to find it but can't `:(`.

Comment: @Andrew: I'd be very interested in that! As it happens, I was facing a very similar problem related to dynamic binding today.

Comment: @NiklasB. Ah it was the reverse of this it seems: trying to use a variables in a method that were defined in a block. ["Is it possible to access block's scope in method?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245947/is-it-possible-to-access-blocks-scope-in-method/9246066#9246066) (oh and what do you know look at the first comment… deja vu!)

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, the other way round it's very simple: `eval('varname', p.binding)`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try the following hack:

```
class Proc
  def call_with_vars(vars, *args)
    Struct.new(*vars.keys).new(*vars.values).instance_exec(*args, &self)
  end
end
```

To be used like this:

```
irb(main):001:0* lambda { foo }.call_with_vars(:foo => 3)
=> 3
irb(main):002:0> lambda { |a| foo + a }.call_with_vars({:foo => 3}, 1)
=> 4
```

This is not a very general solution, though. It would be better if we could give it `Binding` instance instead of a Hash and do the following:

```
l = lambda { |a| foo + a }
foo = 3
l.call_with_binding(binding, 1)  # => 4
```

Using the following, more complex hack, this exact behaviour can be achieved:

```
class LookupStack
  def initialize(bindings = [])
    @bindings = bindings
  end

  def method_missing(m, *args)
    @bindings.reverse_each do |bind|
      begin
        method = eval("method(%s)" % m.inspect, bind)
      rescue NameError
      else
        return method.call(*args)
      end
      begin
        value = eval(m.to_s, bind)
        return value
      rescue NameError
      end
    end
    raise NoMethodError
  end

  def push_binding(bind)
    @bindings.push bind
  end

  def push_instance(obj)
    @bindings.push obj.instance_eval { binding }
  end

  def push_hash(vars)
    push_instance Struct.new(*vars.keys).new(*vars.values)
  end

  def run_proc(p, *args)
    instance_exec(*args, &p)
  end
end

class Proc
  def call_with_binding(bind, *args)
    LookupStack.new([bind]).run_proc(self, *args)
  end
end
```

Basically we define ourselves a manual name lookup stack and `instance_exec` our proc against it. This is a very flexible mechanism. It not only enables the implementation of `call_with_binding`, it can also be used to build up much more complex lookup chains:

```
l = lambda { |a| local + func(2) + some_method(1) + var + a }

local = 1
def func(x) x end

class Foo < Struct.new(:add)
  def some_method(x) x + add end
end

stack = LookupStack.new
stack.push_binding(binding)
stack.push_instance(Foo.new(2))
stack.push_hash(:var => 4)

p stack.run_proc(l, 5)
```

This prints 15, as expected :)

**UPDATE:** Code is now also available [at Github](https://github.com/niklasb/ruby-dynamic-binding). I use this for one my projects too now.

Comment: Minor nitpick: did you mean `lambda { |a| local + func + some_method + a }`? Very cool answer!

Comment: @Brandan: Yes, I also noticed that just now. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @NiklasB. Hey friend, I found a better and more elegant solution, see my code below!

Comment: Doesn't this change what self refers to?  If someone creates a proc that relies on self not being changed, then this will cause problems.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a given in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Proc
    def call_with_obj(obj, *args)
        m = nil
        p = self
        Object.class_eval do
            define_method :a_temp_method_name, &p
            m = instance_method :a_temp_method_name; remove_method :a_temp_method_name
        end
        m.bind(obj).call(*args)
    end
end
```

And then use it as:

```
class Foo
    def bar
        "bar"
    end
end

p = Proc.new { bar }

bar = "baz"

p.call_with_obj(self) # => baz
p.call_with_obj(Foo.new) # => bar
```

Comment: What's the point? Those could just be written as `instance_exec(&p)` or `Foo.new.instance_exec(&p)`. I think you just reinvented the wheel.. My answer was meant to be a lot more general than that, but if `instance_exec` is sufficient, then go for it :) The approach using a temporary method is not particularly elegant, because it's not reentrant (as in, it can't be used in a nested manner, nor can it be used across threads).

Comment: So in a nutshell, I don't consider this "cool", but if it works for you, that's nice :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Oh you are right. I used to just considered about whether I can get rid of string evaluation. I got known the instance_exec after read your answer, but... I'm just really reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't actually need to define `a` later, but instead only need to *set* it later.

Or (as below), perhaps you don't actually need `a` to be a local variable (which itself references an array). Instead, perhaps you can usefully employ a class variable, such as `@@a`. This works for me, by printing "1":

```rb
class SomeClass
  def l
    @l ||= lambda { puts @@a }
  end

  def some_function
    @@a = 1
    l.call
  end
end
SomeClass.new.some_function
```

Answer (score 0):

a similar way:

```rb
class Context
  attr_reader :_previous, :_arguments

  def initialize(_previous, _arguments)
    @_previous = _previous
    @_arguments = _arguments
  end
end

def _code_def(_previous, _arguments = [], &_block)
  define_method("_code_#{_previous}") do |_method_previous, _method_arguments = []|
    Context.new(_method_previous, _method_arguments).instance_eval(&_block)
  end
end

_code_def('something') do
  puts _previous
  puts _arguments
end
```