# block like parameter for Ruby DSL

Tags: ruby, dsl

I have a ruby code that currently look like this:

```
grades.sum{|g| g.grade * g.weight}
```

For a user maintained DSL, I would like to implement something like this:

```
grades.sum('grade' * 'weight')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible unless you monkeypatch the class `String` to add your application logic (please don't do that). But this -which even looks beter- is possible if you play a little bit with `instance_eval`:

```
grades.sum { grade * weight }
```

For example, let's assume `grades` is an array:

```
module Enumerable
  def sum(&block)
    inject(0) { |acc, x| acc + x.instance_eval(&block) }
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this better than my solution. If the curly braces are acceptable instead of parentheses, this reads much more nicely, IMO.

Comment: +1, your answer is getting close to also what I need, and what has been solved on SO already, and what I had no time to investigate until now. But I have an impression that there was just something a bit more to it... I'll be back after some searching.

Comment: Got it. It's [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058996) and [this tool by Niklas B.](https://github.com/niklasb/ruby-dynamic-binding) that fully treat this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, no, because the Ruby interpreter will attempt to multiply the strings "grade" and "weight" together before passing them as a parameter to "sum". You could achieve it by monkeypatching String to override all the operations you want to permit, but that's an awful idea and will be a maintenance nightmare.

Now, that said, you have a couple of ways that you could achieve this. If you require a full string as the parameter:

```
grades.sum('grade * weight')
```

Then, you can use `instance_eval` to `eval` that code in the context of the value you're passing to `#sum`. The implementation would look something like:

```
class Grade
  def weight
    0.5
  end

  def grade
    75
  end
end

class Array
  def sum(code = nil)
    if block_given?
      inject(0) {|s, v| s + yield(v) }
    else
      sum {|v| v.instance_eval code }
    end
  end
end

grades = Array.new(5, Grade.new)
puts grades.sum("weight * grade")

# Expected output: 5 * 75 * 0.5 = 187.5
#
# Actual output:
# % ruby grades.rb
# 187.5
```

This also preserves your original block form:

```
puts grades.sum {|g| g.weight * g.grade } # => 187.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058996) and [this code by Niklas B](https://github.com/niklasb/ruby-dynamic-binding).