# Replace eval(code_string, binding) with lambda?

Tags: ruby, eval

I have a Ruby template engine that uses `eval(code_string, binding, source_file)` and every time this is called Ruby must parse the code string and it is perhaps not as fast as it could be.

I'd like to find an alternative, such as converting `code_string` into a method, e.g. `method = eval("lambda { #{code_string} }")`, before executing it, theoretically `eval(method, binding, source_file)`.

But the problem is, I need to provide a binding and a source file name (and possibly a line number). Basically, I want eval to be able to take a lambda as a first argument, but so far I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Comment: The problem is to make `eval` more efficient by parsing and converting the code to something executable. `eval` is called multiple times with the same inputs.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging, I found this was a relatively common problem after all:

For a "solution" to this exact problem: [Changing the binding of a Proc in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058996/changing-the-binding-of-a-proc-in-ruby)

For some more discussion from the Ruby forum: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/184259

In the end, it appears that what I want is not possible to do efficiently (i.e. without `eval` at some point). But, I can replace my code to use `instance_eval` though it isn't as flexible, but more efficient.