# Is it possible to override value in a block

Tags: ruby

New to Ruby so apologies in advance if this is a dumb question. I have a need to supply a value to a block but would like not to update everywhere called.

Let's say I have the following block:

```
{ base.call_my_test }
```

It get's passed to a function where I'd like to wrap it in another block but supply that other blocks value to it such as:

```
def test(&block)
    MyTest.with_base_object do |base|
        #neither of these work
        block.instance_variable_set(:@base, base) # Doesn't work
        block.define_singleton_method(:hi) do
            return base
        end

        block.call <---- Is it possible to define base here? 
    end
end
```

In the above example, is it possible to define `base` on the block without passing as an argument? I tried `instance_variable_set` as well as `define_singleton_method` but I can't seem to get anything to be defined as it always says `base` is undefined.

Not sure if this is even possible but figured I'd ask.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an optional argument?

Comment: Because I Dont directly control the block being passed. Not optimal but temporary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, blocks in Ruby are [non-rigid](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Proc.html#method-i-lambda-3F) `Proc` objects. That means that you can pass extra arguments, and anyone who doesn't expect arguments will silently ignore them.

```
def test(&block)
  base = Object.new
  block.call(base)
end

test { |x| puts "Works with an object #{x}." }
test { puts "Works without an object as well!" }
```

So if you control the block where you need `base` to be defined, then you can simply add the argument. Any other uses of the `test` function will simply ignore the extra argument, even if they're not declared to take one.

But this is assuming you control *any* of the blocks at all. It sounds like you have some blocks somewhere out there that you can't change, and you automagically want to inject the name `base` into their scope. You can change the class instance that a block is being invoked for by passing the block to [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval).

**Buyer beware:** This will completely change `self`. If the block in question tries to view `self` or call any other methods on the object (it thinks) it's enclosed in, it will fail.

```
class HasBase
  attr_reader :base

  def initialize(base)
    @base = base
  end

end

def test(&block)
  base = Object.new
  HasBase.new(base).instance_eval(&block)
end

test { puts "I can see my #{base} from here!" }
```

Depending on your specific needs, you can start augmenting this to work with whatever your callers need. For instance, you can [write `method_missing` to fall back to the proc's original binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10059209/2288659). But that's getting into some deep magic, and you probably don't want to play with that footgun in production for very long.